# Trying to create a select which options are ranges a field in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I've been looking on google but nothing found.

The ranges of `<option>` will be the minimum and maximum of every 30 rows. For example: `<option>13595-13649</option>`
`<option>13651-13701</option>`

in the id field of the table, some records do not exist, which are uncorrelated.

[image]

Help please.

Comment: can u add your code what you have tried..

Comment: Fetch all you stuff, then save the `["30*n"-th, "30*(n+1)-1"-th]` pair for `n` in `[0, floor(numRecords / 30)]`, done.

Answer (score 1):

Since no direct question exists, I can point you in the right direction of the workflow:
First you will need to create a mysql query to gather all of the data needed to populate the options' values.
Next you should aggregate your data to create the ranges you need, stored in a php variable (most likely and array).
Once you have this, then you will need to create your select, then loop through your dataset to create the dynamic options.

Comment: And to what should it correlate?

Comment: Because your initial Select statement only pulls in the min and max stored. The ids in between are not sequential correct? You should instead do a Select of all ids, put them into an array, sort them, then iterate through them in batches of 30 taking the first and last number and creating your <option> for each iteration.